# How to include any .sty file in circuit_macros?

Tags: macros, packages, include, circuits

My circuit_macros M4 code

```
.PS
#\usepackage{steinmetz}
#include(steinmetz)
#s_init(steinmetz)
scale=25.4
source(up_,AC);llabel(,120\angle 50{^{\circ}},)
.PE
```

output

[image]

And that I want image,

[image]

That is how to include `steinmetz.sty` file?

Related to: http://staff.ee.sun.ac.za/pjrandewijk/wiki/index.php/M4_Circuit_Macros_-_Getting_Started

Related to: http://staff.ee.sun.ac.za/pjrandewijk/wiki/index.php/M4_Circuit_Macros_-_Installation

Related to: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/circuit_macros

Related to: https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~aplevich/Circuit_macros/CMman.pdf (12  Interaction with `\LaTeX` in page 36)

Comment: While I don't think this is off-topic per se, I would be really surprised if it got an answer, it seems a marginal topic to people here...

Comment: If you are using MikTeX, you have to tell the settings (admin) where to find the sty files and then to refresh the FNDB.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, your answer is in Dwight Aplevich's e-mail. I don't use MikTeX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Dwight Aplevich's e-mail

**First Answer, with pstricks**

`test.m4`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{boxdims}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{steinmetz}
\begin{document}
.PS
cct_init
sinclude(test.dim)
s_init(steinmetz)
scale=25.4
command "
\newcommand\Angle[1]{\setbox0=\hbox{$\mskip 7mu minus 4mu#1$}%
\raise.21ex\hbox{$/$}\hskip-0.95ex\underline{\raise\dp0\hbox{\box0}}}
"
[
source(up_,AC); llabel(,120\Angle{50^{\circ}},)
source(up_,AC); llabel(,120\angle{50^{\circ}},)
source(up_,AC); llabel(,s_box(120\phase{50^{\circ}}),)
]
showbox_
.PE
\end{document}
```

1) `m4 pstricks.m4 test.m4 | dpic -p > test4.tex; latex test`

2) `m4 pstricks.m4 test.m4 | dpic -p > test4.tex; latex test ; dvips test`

[image]

**Second Answer, with Tikz**

`file.m4`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,steinmetz}
\begin{document}
.PS
cct_init
scale=25.4
source(,AC); llabel(,120\phase{50^{\circ}},)
.PE
\end{document}
```

`m4 pgf.m4 file.m4 | dpic -g > file.tex; pdflatex file`

[image]

Thank you Dwight Aplevich.